# How to print strings using bios interrupts

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am working on an assigment on creating an operating system using some assembly functions and 16 bit C compiler. My task is to print strings on screen using 0x10 interrupt. Since interrupts can be called in assembly file, I have been provided with an assembly file which contains a function called interrupt which takes five arguments : the interrupt number, and the interrupt parameters passed in the `AX`, `BX`, `CX`, and `DX`. 
For example, to print 'Q' with the provided function, I need to write like this:

```
char al = 'Q'
char ah = 0xE
int ax = ah*256+al;
interrupt(0x10,ax,0,0,0);
```

OR, simply:

```
interrupt(0x10,0xE*256+'Q',0,0,0);
```

in a *C* program called `kernel.c`

My task is to write a function `printString(char *chars)` in *C* which takes a string and prints it on screen using the discussed assembly function.

I have done it this way:

```
void printString(char * chars){
int i = 0; 
int l = length(chars);
 for(; i < l; i++){
   interrupt(0x10,0xE*256+chars[i],0,0,0);
 }
}
```

but it prints the string multiple times instead of printing one time.
when I try to print "Hello World", it's printed 11 times, because it contains 11 characters, same is the case with other strings.

Comment: You probably have a problem on the code that handles the interrupt. Can you add it as well?

Comment: Wouldn't be `strlen()` instead of `length()`? Does this code actually compiles? Or is `length()` a custom function to get the length of the string? In that case, can you add it?

Comment: This is a decent exercise to get started, but using the bios is not the way to write an OS. The proper way to write things to the screen is to write a driver for the video interface.

Comment: i defined length myself because i used no c predefined functions - length is not an issue

Comment: Instead of using length() you may use a different for loop: "for(i=0;chars[i]!=0;i++)". However this will not solve your actual problem. Maybe the problem is also located in the function that calls the function printString().

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look for a null character to terminate the read. I've noticed the assembly file does some weird stuff with the character buffers too. I even had multiple characters print when I called the interrupt function directly from main().

Adding the line: while(1); keeps main() from returning. The boot loader executing multiple instances of main() is what causes the repeated output.